# Can't ChromeDriver headless to work on Centos 7

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to get Selenium Testing working with Chrome Headless (we are currently using remote selenium web driver, which works fine but is very slow).  The ChromeDriver is instantiated with:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");   
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920x1080");
chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false);
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

dr = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

(I've tried it both only using setHeadless, and only using --headless as an argument, I figured I should be double sure so the code currently includes both).  The logs show:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304) on port 1848
[0.705][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920x1080" ],
            "binary": "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
            "extensions": [  ],
            "prefs": {
               "credentials_enable_service": false,
               "password_manager_enabled": false
            }
         }
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920x1080" ],
            "binary": "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
            "extensions": [  ],
            "prefs": {
               "credentials_enable_service": false,
               "password_manager_enabled": false
            }
         }
      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920x1080" ],
         "binary": "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
         "extensions": [  ],
         "prefs": {
            "credentials_enable_service": false,
            "password_manager_enabled": false
         }
      }
   }
}
[0.708][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[0.708][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[0.712][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --full-memory-crash-report --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ZsjTh0/internal --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12771 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.lVGXx8 data:,
[0.714][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[0.732][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[1.457][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.507][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[1.514][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.564][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[1.569][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.620][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[1.624][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.674][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[1.678][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.728][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[1.732][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
[1.782][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version
[1.786][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed

(google-chrome:1887): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

And then a ton more "DevTools request: http://127.0.0.1:12771/json/version,  DevTools request failed" lines (hundreds and hundreds).

I've tried with Selenium 3.7.1 and then tried by updating to Selenium 3.12.0, with no change in the output.

Chrome is installed (version 66.0.3359.181), as is ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304), and the whole thing is working on Centos 7 box with no Window Manager.  While the command line that ChromeDriver appears to be Launching Chrome with fails from the commandline:

```
$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --full-memory-crash-report --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ZsjTh0/internal --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12771 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.lVGXx8 data:,

(google-chrome:3346): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

it succeeds if I add --headless to the line.

```
$ /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --headless --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --full-memory-crash-report --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ZsjTh0/internal --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12771 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.lVGXx8 data:,
[0529/154351.972190:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12771/devtools/browser/a008b11c-d1c3-4c56-ba28-7f221eed4507
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 146: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
```

This setup works fine on my Windows box (but the Launching Chrome request on my windows box does include --headless parameter).  I'm unsure as to why ChromeDriver doesn't appear to be passing any of the chromeOptions (--headless, --disable-gpu or --window=1920x1024) to the chrome process when launching.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Your code block is almost perfect. A couple of things:

- If you look at the source code of `setHeadless()`, the `--headless` flag is already implemented. So setting explicitly `addArguments("--headless")` will be overhead. You can remove the argument.

  ```
  def set_headless(self, headless=True):
      """
      Sets the headless argument

      Args:
        headless: boolean value indicating to set the headless option
      """
      args = {'--headless', '--disable-gpu'}
      if headless:
          self._arguments.extend(args)
      else:
          self._arguments = list(set(self._arguments) - args)
  ```
- However your main issue is the **incompatibility** among the binary versions you are using as follows:

  - You are using *chromedriver=2.9*
  - Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.9*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :
  - > Supports **Chrome v31-34**
  - You are using *chrome=66.0*
  - Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :
  - > Supports **Chrome v65-67**
- So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver* **v2.9** and the *Chrome Browser* **v66.0**

### Solution

- Keep *JDK* upgraded to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Keep *Selenium* upgraded to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: OP was asking about Java... but this answer shows Python source?